# ActionBar сливается с разметкой

Tags: android

Я устанавливаю кастомный `Action Bar`:

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View titleView = vi.inflate(R.layout.action_bar, null);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(titleView);
```

Разметка `ActionBar`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/black" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Но он почему-то сливается с черным цветом кнопки (кнопка немного светлее), как на фото, но с белым цветом, отделяется:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот разметка `main.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#393939"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background_one"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background_one"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Из вопросы совершенно непонятно, что именно вас не устраивает. ActionBar и кнопки разных цветов.

Comment: @saturov, на втором скриншоте - да, но на первом цвет бара и кнопки сливается (не видно четкой линии). Почему это происходит?

Comment: Эффект тени потому что

Comment: @АндройдАндройд, и как его убрать?

Comment: Можно в стилях (погугли если что), можно в коде таким образом getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ActionBar сливается с одинаковым цветом кнопки, а мб и просто тень от ActionBar если она есть. Замените отступ в LinearLayout

```
android:paddingBottom="1dp"
```

К примеру на:

```
android:padding="2dp"
```

Тогда отступ будет не только снизу (где у Вас есть, как бы разделительная линия) но и от ActionBar.